# Writing databricks dataframe to S3 using python

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I have a databricks data frame called df. I want to write it to a S3 bucket as a csv file. I have the S3 bucket name and other credentials. I checked the online documentation given here https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html#mount-aws-s3 and it says to use following commands

```py
dbutils.fs.mount(s"s3a://$AccessKey:$SecretKey@$AwsBucketName", s"/mnt/$MountName", "sse-s3")

dbutils.fs.put(s"/mnt/$MountName", "<file content>")
```

But what I have is a dataframe and not a file. How can I achieve it?

Comment: try `df.write.csv('/mnt/mountname/filename.csv')` or for more options see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I found two solutions

**1srt**

```
df
.write \
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
.option("header", "true") \
.save("s3a://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, BUCKET_NAME, DIRECTORY)))
```

Worked like a charm.

**2nd**

You can indeed mount an S3 Bucket and then write a file to it directly like this :

```
#### MOUNT AND READ S3 FILES
AWS_BUCKET_NAME = "your-bucket-name"
MOUNT_NAME = "a-directory-name"
dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s" % AWS_BUCKET_NAME, "/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME)
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/%s" % MOUNT_NAME))

#### WRITE FILE 

df.write.save('/mnt/{}/{}'.format(MOUNT_NAME, "another-directory-name"), format='csv')
```

This is also going to sync to your S3 Bucket.

Comment: this line is missing that why unable to connect `encoded_secret_key = secret_key.replace("/", "%2F")`. After applying, successfully connected. It is mentioned on https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html#mount-aws-s3